# Sort objects by date = T.get_date() confusion

Tags: sorting, object

Following a guide in a book::

I cannot figure out why the top version does not sort my objects by date value, while I got the bottom one to do the same. The top is a list of objects, the bottom is a list of strings. I added in some print statements just so I could see what is compared to be sure everything gets compared and they do, but no swap occurs.

```
 l = len(list_of_objects)
 for n in list_of_objects:
   holder = n.get_date()
   holder = int(holder)
   mp = n
   for i in list_of_objects:
       top = i.get_date()
       top = int(top)
       print(holder, 'vs', top)
       if top < holder:
           mp = i
   n, mp = mp, n

sort_list = []

l = len(list_of_objects)

####Sorter#### 
print('Sorting Data')
for T in list_of_objects:
    string = str(T.get_date())+':'+str(T.get_transaction_type())+':'+str(T.get_amount())
    sort_list.insert(0,string)
    
for bottom in range(l-1):
    lower = sort_list[bottom]
    holder = lower[0:8]
    mp = bottom
    for i in range(bottom+1,l):
        top = sort_list[i]
        top = top[0:8]
        if top < holder:
            mp = i
     
    print(bottom, holder, top)
    sort_list[bottom], sort_list[mp] = sort_list[mp], sort_list[bottom]
```

Answer (score 0):

Screw the book's method. I just made a sequence key the easy way using sorted() and numerical values for dates. Then found a way to update the list by appending values to a new list as they were found to match and removing entries from the old list as they were used.

s_list =[]
updated_list_of_objects = []
for i in list_of_objects:
s_list.append(i.get_date())
s_list = sorted(s_list)

count = 0
for m in s_list:
for n in list_of_objects:
date = n.get_date()
if date == m:
updated_list_of_objects.append(n)
list_of_objects.remove(n)
count =+ 1

list_of_objects = updated_list_of_objects

Answer (score 0):

```
 s_list =[]
   updated_list_of_objects = []
   for i in list_of_objects:
       s_list.append(i.get_date())
       s_list = sorted(s_list)

  
   count = 0
   for m in s_list:
       for n in list_of_objects:
           date = n.get_date()
           if date == m:     
               updated_list_of_objects.append(n)
               list_of_objects.remove(n)
               count =+ 1
              
   list_of_objects = updated_list_of_objects
```